# find duplicate query in Sql server

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have no Primary key in my table.
only just first name,last name and salary only.
i want result like .number of duplicate row occurrence.(first name duplicate) .
also delete those duplicate record.
so could you help me on behalf of this .

Answer (score 0):

To find them use

```
select first_name, count(*)
from your_table
group by first_name
having count(*) > 1
```

But if you want to delete them be careful to choose which you want to delete.